# Manually download jar and build from Intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I hava a jar file which I downloaded manually from the maven repository and I put it into the .m2 repository folder. But when I try to build the project using Intellij IDE it still trying to download the same jar, how to let the IDE knows that the jar file is already there and skip download it again ?

I have checked the following

- that the jar file is placed into the folder structure based on group id, artifact id and version
- tried maven -> Reload project
- tried File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

Just coping a jar to `.m2` directory does not really work. You will need to `install` this jar file. In order to do so, you will have us use the following maven command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=my.jar\
  -DgroupId=my.jar.group\
  -DartifactId=my\
  -Dversion=1.0-jar-version\
  -Dpackaging=jar
```

You should replace the values in this command with the correct ones.